# Laravel Scout and MeiliSearch integration in Laradock

Tags: php, laravel, laradock, laravel-scout, meilisearch

I'm trying to integrate [MeiliSearch](https://www.meilisearch.com/) in my Laravel project using their [official package](https://github.com/meilisearch/meilisearch-laravel-scout) for Laravel scout. Am using [Laradock](https://laradock.io/) as a development environment and it has a pre-installed Meilisearch docker image.

I couldn't find anything that explains how to achieve this and here is where got lost, whenever I try to access MeiliSearch host -> http://localhost:7700 from Laradock workspace container it returns *Connection refused* but it works fine when trying to access it from my computer bash

Answer (score 5):

I just figured it out after reading how networking works in docker

it turns out I have to use meilisearch instead of localhost in my host address

from

```
MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://localhost:7700
```

to

```
MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://meilisearch:7700
```